# Dependancy error when building maven project

Tags: svn, java, jenkins, continuous-integration, maven

I'm trying to move an application from being built locally on a Windows Eclipse installation to a Jenkins server. From what I can see the settings are correct and the dependencies should resolve. Even the ones it is complaining about are there when I check the ~/.m2/repositories/ folder. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here. I'm completely new to Jenkins and little to no experience with Maven itself.

Here's my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.my.project</groupId>
    <artifactId>My-Project</artifactId>
    <name>MyProject</name>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->

        <!-- AspectJ -->

        <!-- Logging -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- @Inject -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- CUSTOM -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
            <version>0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
            <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
            <version>1.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-adapters</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jdom</groupId>
            <artifactId>jdom2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jms</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.10.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.3-1102-jdbc41</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
            <artifactId>ehcache</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>jboss-logging</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.4.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime</groupId>
            <artifactId>viewservlets</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-common</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.xmlrpc</groupId>
            <artifactId>xmlrpc-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <scm>
        <connection>scm:svn:http://192.168.1.88:18080/svn/project</connection>
        <tag>HEAD</tag>
        <url>scm:svn:http://192.168.1.88:18080/svn/project</url>
    </scm>
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                    <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                            <pluginExecutions>
                                <pluginExecution>
                                    <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                                        <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                                        <versionRange>[1.0,)</versionRange>
                                        <goals>
                                            <goal>create</goal>
                                        </goals>
                                    </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <action>
                                        <execute>
                                            <runOnIncremental>true</runOnIncremental>
                                        </execute>
                                    </action>
                                </pluginExecution>
                            </pluginExecutions>
                        </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>buildnumber-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>create</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <doCheck>false</doCheck>
                    <doUpdate>false</doUpdate>
                    <timestampFormat>{0,date,yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}</timestampFormat>
                    <revisionOnScmFailure>unknownbuild</revisionOnScmFailure>
                    <providerImplementations>
                        <svn>javasvn</svn>
                    </providerImplementations>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>com.google.code.maven-scm-provider-svnjava</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-scm-provider-svnjava</artifactId>
                        <version>2.0.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.tmatesoft.svnkit</groupId>
                        <artifactId>svnkit</artifactId>
                        <version>1.8.5</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <additionalProjectnatures>
                        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                    </additionalProjectnatures>
                    <additionalBuildcommands>
                        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                    </additionalBuildcommands>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
                        </manifest>
                        <manifestEntries>
                            <Implementation-Build>${buildNumber}</Implementation-Build>
                        </manifestEntries>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Here are the errors I get when I try to clean the project from the command line (I get the same plus a whole lot more when I try to build in Jenkins):

```
[root@localhost workspace]# /opt/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn clean install -U
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building My-Project 1.0
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-logging/commons-logging-adapters/1.1/commons-logging-adapters-1.1.pom
[WARNING] The POM for commons-logging:commons-logging-adapters:jar:1.1 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-discovery/axis/1.4/axis-1.4.pom
[WARNING] The POM for commons-discovery:axis:jar:1.4 is missing, no dependency information available
Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/commons-discovery/axis/1.4/axis-1.4.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.228 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-02-10T16:01:34-05:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 16M/152M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project My-Project: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.my.project:My-Project:war:1.0: Could not find artifact commons-discovery:axis:jar:1.4 in central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
[root@localhost workspace]#
```

Any help is appreciated as I've scoured the web as best as I can. Please keep in mind that this project builds without any errors from Eclipse so that's why I believe it's a settings issue on the Linux server.

Edit: I've even tried to move/delete the entire ~/.m2/repositories/ folder and run an "mvn clean install -U"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found a partial solution around the problem. I invoked maven from the command line with:

```
sudo -u jenkins /opt/apache-maven-3.2.5/bin/mvn archetype:generate -DgroupId=org.eclipse.m2e -DartifactId=lifecycle-mapping -Dversion=1.0.0 -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-mojo
```

this gets past the particular problem, but I'm running into others. I'll make another post for that.

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like the commons-discovery:axis:jar has either been moved or that's not the correct GAV.

I see this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>axis</groupId>
  <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
  <version>(PUT YOUR VERSION HERE)</version>
</dependency>
```

And this:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-discovery</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-discovery</artifactId>
  <version>(PUT YOUR VERSION HERE)</version>
</dependency>
```

Another kind off thing I see is you seem to be hitting repo1/maven central direct with no proxy.

I'd strongly suggest setting this kinda thing up to help prevent errors when artifacts move (the redirects don't seem to always work and for sure don't last forever).